# Error loading audio javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, audio

How can I tell if an audio element had an error when loading,

To check if it has loaded I am using

```
// Load handler
                audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
                    // Load success
                    this._loadSuccess(audio, name, info, "audio");
                }.bind(this), false);
```

With image I can use `error` but it doesn't work with audio?

Comment: Check this link

http://html5center.sourceforge.net/Unlocking-the-power-of-HTML5-audio

In the link , 'find' for h.addEventListener("error",$.proxy(this,"handleAudioError"),false)

Comment: Thank you, will check this out :), Very good link thanks